# Difference between a local extreme and a local minimum/maximum

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I often see these two terms being used (mainly in Calculus books) and I never know if they mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably or not. Does anyone know ?

Comment: The terms may be used interchangeably. Extrema refers to a location where the derivative is $0$ and 2nd derivative non-zero. Maximums and minimums are both types of extrema

Comment: There might be a few isolated exceptions, but in the vast majority of the books I've seen, "extrema" means "maximum or minimum". And "local extrema" means "local maximum or local minimum", "global extrema" means . . .

Comment: @infinitylord: Extrema is usually defined in such a way that differentiability is not assumed. For example, most books would say that $0$ is an extrema for the absolute value function.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

A local extreme can be either a local minimum or a local maximum.  Sometimes you just care that it is just one or the other, not which one.

Comment: Aha, that's what I thought, it was just weird that none of the books ever stressed this before. Or maybe they just assumed people would make the connection.